# Large 2D state array causing lag in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a graph drawing application and I hold all my data points in a large 2D state array in react. I notice that react starts to lag when I try to keep track of too many individual points in my graph. How can I optimize my code to make it more efficient?

```
import { useState } from "react";

function classNames(...classes) {
    return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

const Square = ({ squareVal, setSquareVal }) => {
    return (
        <button
            className={classNames("h-1 w-1", squareVal ? "bg-red-600" : "bg-gray-300")}
            onMouseEnter={setSquareVal}
        ></button>
    );
}

const Column = ({ columnArr, columnInd, columnSquareSelected }) => {
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col">
            {columnArr.map((sqrVal, sqrInd) => (
                <Square
                    key={columnInd + " " + sqrInd}
                    squareVal={sqrVal}
                    setSquareVal={() => columnSquareSelected(columnInd, sqrInd)}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    const width = 200;
    const length = 200;
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(Array(width).fill(Array(length).fill(false))); // 1st array represents columns, 2nd array represents squares

    const columnSquareSelected = (columnInd, squareInd) => {
        const newSelected = selected.slice(0); // changes the array refrence since react changes state based on refrence
        const newColumn = Array(length).fill(false);
        newColumn.splice(squareInd, 1, true)
        newSelected.splice(columnInd, 1, newColumn);
        setSelected(newSelected);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h1 className="text-5xl large font-semibold">Heart Rate Faker</h1>
                <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold">Create fake heart rate data</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                {selected.map((columnArr, columnInd) => (
                    <Column
                        key={columnInd}
                        columnArr={columnArr}
                        columnInd={columnInd}
                        columnSquareSelected={(columnInd, squareInd) => columnSquareSelected(columnInd, squareInd)}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cold-haze-zd2tpj?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A13%2C48) is a code sandbox